# Update picklist field using workflow rule

Tags: workflow, administration, formula-field, field-update

I have a object called job application and another object called Interview. On interview I have a lookup relationship field to the job application object.

I have a picklist field called status in job application. I have a pick list field called recommendation in Interview. I would like to update the status on job application based on the recommendation field. How can I achieve this? Is it possible through workflow rule? or is there any approach?

Comment: Creating a Trigger would be best option. Because, for every time it should take dynamically based on Child Object Field.

Comment: I tried process builder which solves this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a workflow rule you cannot update a field on Master object based on a field on child(lookup relation) object. In this scenario you wish to update the status field on job application(Master) using the recommendation field on Interview object( child object). This can be achieved by creating a process builder on Interview object where you set the criteria as based on recommendation fields and in immediate action you should select update a record(job application), then set the status field to the value you want.

Comment: Rdvsm.. can you pls add steps what you followed?